# Looping over optimisation

Tags: loops, gams-math

I have been trying to loop over an optimisation problem, each time changing only one parameter in order to perform a sensitivity analysis. Yet, everytime I perform the loop it only uses one of the parameters. So I will get the same result 30 times.

This is where the parameter needs to be changed

```
Set n   /i1*i30/

Parameter                         
                X0(i)           household consumption of the i-th good
                F0(h,j)         the h-th factor input by the j-th firm
                Z0(j)           output of the j-th good
                FF(h)           factor endowment of the h-th factor
                RT0(j)          Monopoly rents
                gamma           Price elasticity of demand
                gamma_l(n)      Different gamma /i1 1.1, i2 2,i3 3, i4 4, i5 5, i6 6, i7 7,i8 8, i9 9,i10 10, i11 11,i12 12, i13 13, i14 14, i15 15, i16 16, i17 17, i18 18,
                                                i19 19, i20 20, i21 21, i22 22, i23 23, i24 24, i25 25, i26 26, i27 27, i28 28, i29 29, i30 30/
                results_UU(n)
                results_px(i,n) Prices for goods
                results_x(i,n)  Quantities of goods
eta             Elasticity of substitution
                ;

X0(i)   =SAM(i,"HOH");

gamma= 1.1;
eta=(gamma-1)/gamma;
```

This is the loop over the optimisation.

```
loop(n,
gamma=gamma_l(n);
Solve splcge maximizing UU using nlp;
results_UU(n)=UU.l;
results_px(i,n)=px.l(i);
results_x(i,n)=X.l(i)
;);
```

Comment: Are you forgetting to update this piece:
    eta=(gamma-1)/gamma;?

Comment: You mean in the loop itself?
`loop(n,  
gamma=gamma_l(n);  
eta=(gamma-1)/gamma;  
Solve splcge maximizing UU using nlp;  
results_UU(n)=UU.l;  
results_px(i,n)=px.l(i);  
results_x(i,n)=X.l(i)  
;);`

Comment: It is not changed automatically as it is not an equation in a model, but rather a one off data assignment. If you want it updated when you change gamma, you need to do so, or make eta a variable and add    eta =E= (gamma-1)/gamma    as an equation.

Comment: Yeah, that worked. I just had to insert the initializing equations in the loop like so
`loop(n,
gamma=gamma_l(n);
eta=(gamma-1)/gamma;
RT0(j)  =(1-eta)*X0(j);
F0(h,j) =SAM(h,j)-SAM(h,j)/sum(k, SAM(k,j))*RT0(j);
Z0(j)   =sum(h, F0(h,j));
FF(h)   =  sum(j, F0(h,j));
Solve splcge maximizing UU using nlp;
results_UU(n)=UU.l;
results_px(i,n)=px.l(i);
results_x(i,n)=X.l(i)
;);`

Thanks alot for the quick help!